# How to serialize NSManagedObject to JSON in restkit 0.20?

Tags: objective-c, restkit

How to serialize NSManagedObject to JSON in restkit 0.20 using inverse mapping?

Right now I don't need to post anything anywhere.

I would like manually create object MyObjectManaged.
Set some attributes for example:
id,
name,
age

Map them with existing mapping my mapping to JSON attributes:
userid,
first_name,
age

create and print JSON.

Is it possible? When yes, how?
 Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Nru You did not specify platform, OS or version. However, take a look at [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html "NSJSONSerialization") Frank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've recently been trying to do the same thing :)  I wanted to keep the mappings so that eventually I can hook up to a server, but also reuse them for serializing objects out to a file.

I did this using the inverseMapping and running it through an RKMappingOperation.

First set up your mappings from JSON -> Core Data Object

```
RKEntityMapping mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"MyManagedObject" inManagedObjectStore:rkManagedObjectStore];
[self.nodeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"userid": @"id",
    @"first_name": @"name",
    @"age": @"age"
}];
```

Then use the inverse mapping to map your object instance (e.g. "myObject") to a dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
RKObjectMappingOperationDataSource *dataSource = [RKObjectMappingOperationDataSource new];
RKMappingOperation *operation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:myObject 
                                                               destinationObject:jsonDict
                                                                         mapping:[mapping inverseMapping]];
operation.dataSource = dataSource;

NSError *error = nil;
[operation performMapping:&error];
```

Assuming there's no error, you can then serialize the dictionary:

```
NSData *data = [RKMIMETypeSerialization dataFromObject:jsonDict 
                                              MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON 
                                                 error:&error];
```

Not sure what you wanted to do with it from there, but if you wanted to print it to a string you could do:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I am trying to make the above code work with an entity that has a Date attribute and I get a crash *due to uncaught exception '**NSInvalidArgumentException**', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)'*. Any ideas what should be changed to make it work with Date attributes?

Comment: @veducm, to solve this exception I recommend you to use the proposed solution by JorgeDeCorte because RKObjectParameterization implements RKMappingOperationDelegate with value transformers by default. In case that you want use the accepted solution you must set the delegate of RKMappingOperation and to implement "mappingOperation:didSetValue:forKeyPath:usingMapping:". If you want to see an example in RKObjectParameterization is implemented

Answer (score 3):

John Martin answer seems to work but I got the problem that NSManagedObject instances with a NSNumber property that is set with

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:boolvalue]
```

serializes a json as value 1/0 instead of true/false. 
Our backend could not handle numbers as booleans.

I solved this with using the RestKit built in class: RKObjectParameterization

Using the follow method my NSManagedObjects were properly serialized when there was an NSNumber property that was set as a bool.

```
+ (NSString *)getJsonObjectWithDescriptor:(RKRequestDescriptor *)requestDescriptor objectToParse:(id)objectToParse {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [RKObjectParameterization parametersWithObject:objectToParse requestDescriptor:requestDescriptor error:&error];
    NSData *data = [RKMIMETypeSerialization dataFromObject:jsonDict
                                                  MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON
                                                     error:&error];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can head over to the RestKit wiki and have a look in the [object mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping). In the paragraph "Object Parameterization & Serialization" you'll find the information about the serialization and inverse mapping.